# Get latest block info with gas price, block time etc., from etherscan.io

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, etherscan, python

I am trying to collect information such as,
`'fast': 140, 'fastest': 165, 'safeLow': 100, 'average': 120, 'block_time': 8.875, 'blockNum': 10021935, 'speed': 0.8993211072506393,....etc.` on the latest Ethereum block.

There are bunch of API provided in `https://etherscan.io/apis` but I am unable to get what I want. Any clue is highly appreciated.

The above example is shown from `https://ethgasstation.info/api/ethgasAPI.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etherscan currently doesn't offer similar information through its API. They have two endpoints for providing gas information, but probably don't cover your need. See details at https://etherscan.io/apis#gastracker

If Eth Gas station is providing the right information, why don't you use that? You can find full documentation on their site https://docs.ethgasstation.info/.

### Gas Price

Returns the fast, standard and safe low prices, along with the current block.

https://ethgasstation.info/api/ethgasAPI.json

**Example response**

```
{  
   "fast":50.0,
   "fastest":200.0,
   "safeLow":10.0,
   "average":20.0,
   "block_time":13.942307692307692,
   "blockNum":7403346,
   "speed":0.7090284960673774,
   "safeLowWait":13.4,
   "avgWait":1.8,
   "fastWait":0.5,
   "fastestWait":0.5
}
```

Comment: thank you @wslyvh, I wanted to check whether the price differs from oracle to oracle.

Comment: Makes sense. So you could check the data from ETHGas station first and then pick the Gwei value of any timing that you want (e.g. the average) to compare it's wait time (e.g. avgWait) to that of Etherscan's with their endpoint.

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=gastracker&action=gasestimate&gasprice=2000000000&apikey=YourApiKeyToken